# Mongoengine check if connection has been successful

Tags: python, connection, mongoengine

I'd like to check whether my script connected to mongoDB successfully. I am using Python and mongoengine. How can I do that? It looks like the connect() method is not actually connecting to the database: if I give it wrong credentials it doesn't raise an error until I run a query on mongo.

Comment: looking at the [`connect`](https://github.com/MongoEngine/mongoengine/blob/master/mongoengine/connection.py) implementation suggests a `ConnectionError` is raised if it can not be reached. You can always try listing the collections or another small query and raise later that way if it is not working for you,

Comment: So do you think there is no official function to test the connection?

Comment: It seems from the implementation there is not. All it is using is the default `MongoClient`